# Segula for netilat yadayim apply when using other peoples' water?

Tags: netilat-yadayim-washing, segulah, parnassah-livelihood

> "Rabbi Chisda said: I wash my hands with an abundance of water and I
> am granted an abundance of goodness" (Shabbat 62b).

There's also a story from the Zohar with Rabbi Elazar Ben Shimon, Rabbi Yoezer and Rashbi that I've heard that associates this abundance and goodness with wealth (does anyone have the source?).

Many if not the majority of times we do netilat yadayim, we do so using someone else's water. Whether it be our shabbat host, or our shul or yeshiva, the point is, someone else is paying for the water. It's common for water rates to be set by usage by volume.

In some countries where yidden live, as well as in Talmudic times, water is/was likely in many cases far more expensive/labour intensive than it is compared to nowadays, in first world countries with indoor plumbing and abundant cheap clean water (Hodu laShem ki tov). Even in first world countries, even if it is less than a pruta, there is what to consider<sup>1</sup>. It might be ok if it is generally people don't mind and it is less than a pruta<sup>2</sup>, but it is still better not to<sup>3</sup> (which would certainly be something that can affect the fulfilment of a segula)

Therefore, it's quite ironic to consider taking more water than necessary to secure a segula for wealth when someone else is paying for that water!

Is there any discussion of this? Does this segula only apply when it's your own water? I believe the story in the Zohar might imply that (i.e. the reward for using extra water to keep the halachot as meticulously as possible, even though it costs you more money, your reward is, poetically, wealth). Or perhaps this segula will extend to our host and we should do so for their sake? Or perhaps we are simply to assume that our host would wish us to use more water in order to guarantee we fulfil the halacha meticulously, segula aside.

Perhaps, perhaps, perhaps, does anyone discuss this?

---

<sup>1 Shulchan Aruch CM 348:1, Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 182:1</sup>
<sup>2 Shulchan Aruch CM 359:1, Kitzur Shulchan Aruch CM 182:1</sup>
<sup>3 Rama 359:1</sup>

Comment: https://www-koltorah-org.cdn.ampproject.org/v/s/www.koltorah.org/articles/avrahams-hachnasat-orechim-by-moshe-davis?amp_gsa=1&amp_js_v=a9&format=amp&usqp=mq331AQKKAFQArABIIACAw%3D%3D#amp_tf=From%20%251%24s&aoh=16740138473089&referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com&ampshare=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.koltorah.org%2Farticles%2Favrahams-hachnasat-orechim-by-moshe-davis

Comment: I assume most people in countries with indoor plumbing don't mind at all if you use the extra water. The only time I know someone ask people to use less water was when the city was working on the street and shut off their water temporarily.

Comment: @N.T. that's not a good assumption in Israel

Comment: @DoubleAA I'll take your word for it.

Comment: If the considerations you mention in the third paragraph (and footnotes) should be applied to the _segula_ of _netilat yadayim_ with abundance of water, so much more should they be applied when no such _segula_ is involved. Does that mean that a guest for a Shabbat/Yom-Tov meal should, besides doing _netilat yadayim_ with a _revi'it_ of water, eat only a _kabeitza_ of bread, drink just enough not to choke on one's food, and eat just a taste of every dish (enough to compliment his hosts on their cooking), lest he be robbing his hosts of more than a _pruta_'s worth of food?

Comment: I'd say if there was a segula for eating 6 kezeitim of bread and 3 reviits of wine, and one would do so at someone else's house without asking, it might be similar to the question? What do you think @TamirEvan?

Comment: @RabbiKaii I'd say that if washing hands with an abundance of water as a guest could be considered to be allowed because it is a _segula_, then if it were not a _segula_, there would be no question that it wouldn't be allowed, on account of _gezel pruta_. So, a guest should definitely not partake in other activities that have no _segula_ associated with them, beyond the required minimum, lest he comes to _gezel pruta_. What do you think?

Comment: I think your pilpul is strong but dependant on things that might be part of the answer to my question that I don't know yet. It is normative for a host to expect a guest to eat to satisfaction, rather than the minimum. So that is normal, and perhaps they also expect a normal amount of water, not an abundance?

Comment: @RabbiKaii "_So that is normal, and perhaps they also expect a normal amount of water, not an abundance?_" Perhaps when Rav Chisda talks about מלא חפני מיא ([handfuls of water](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shabbat.62b.17?lang=bi&vside=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English|en&with=Translation%20Open&lang2=he)), though abundantly more than the minimum _revi'it_, he still means something that's well within an expected normal amount of water, as used today?

Comment: @TamirEvan indeed. This could be the answer. Would need some source though